# Regex date pattern matching

Tags: regex

I am novice in regex. Like to know the below date pattern.

```
(\\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[012]|[0]{2}))
```

I just know,

- `0[1-9]` is 01 or 12 or.... 19
- `1[012]` is 10 or 11 or 12
- `[0]{2}` is 0000 ?
- `\\d{2}` is ?

Comment: `0[1-9]` is not `01` or `12` or `19`, it is either `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 or 09`. You really should read about regex, head on to [regular expressions info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: @Sniffer Notice the "...".

Comment: @arshajii I noticed it but nevertheless `0[1-9]` is never a `12`.

Comment: @Sniffer Oh, I misread that myself.

Comment: @ arshajii / Sniffer - sorry for the typo and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8):

`\d` is a predefined character class that is generally equivalent to `[0-9]` (sometimes it also includes unicode digits, depending on the regex engine). Moreover, `{n}` is a quantifier, and `X{n}` matches `X` exactly `n` times. Therefore, `\d{2}` matches 2 consecutive digits.

Also, `[0]{2}` is 2 consecutive `0`s: `00` (not `0000`).

You're also slightly off about `0[1-9]`: it matches any of `01`, `02`, ..., `09` (`1` can't be at the start). You're correct about `1[012]`.

Overall, this is what your regex looks like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you want to read more about them, a great online reference regarding regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

---

Note that in the above answer I've assumed you mean `\d` by `\\d`, and have used the latter because you're representing the regex in a string format that requires `\`s to be escaped. When representing generic regexes, however, it's best to leave `\`s unescaped. In other words, `\\d` might be interpreted as a literal backslash followed by a `d`, so `\\d{4}` would match `\dddd`. Presumably this isn't what you mean;

Comment: Awesome Tool :) +1 for that ^^